# I want button to do simply task, execute php code

Tags: php, mysql, button

I want my button to do simple task, when i click on it it should send

```
                        $sql = "UPDATE `user` SET `free`=2 WHERE username='$username'";
                        $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
                        $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

but without refreshing. I know how to do it, but everytime i click on button it refresh page ( tried with a href that set up to other page etc). Is any way to set it so?

I meant not send, but execute this one.

Comment: You know how to do it but you don't? Maybe you should search for AJAX.

Comment: Take a look at AJAX - you can use JavaScript for this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

your looking for ajax

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29)

Most (maybe all) javascript frameworks have wrappers for AJAX to make it easier

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

and

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

for example

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you using AJAX to send your data to a PHP page that will do the task you want.

With Javascript:

> function loadXMLDoc() {
>       var xmlhttp;
>
> ```
> if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
>     // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
>     xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
> } else {
>     // code for IE6, IE5
>     xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
> }
>
> xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
>     if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 ) {
>        if(xmlhttp.status == 200){
>            document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
>        }
>        else if(xmlhttp.status == 400) {
>           alert('There was an error 400')
>        }
>        else {
>            alert('something else other than 200 was returned')
>        }
>     }
> }
>
> xmlhttp.open("GET", "ajax_info.txt", true);
> xmlhttp.send(); } </script>
> ```

With jQuery:

> $.ajax({
>       url: "test.html",
>       context: document.body,
>       success: function(){
>         $(this).addClass("done");
>       } });